# finding the resultant using paralellogram method to find the resultant

Tags: vectors, physics, resultant

for some reason I don't understand my prof again...
we were doing online class since there is a super typhoon so they suspended face to face, since it is not face to face it is hard to understand what the prof will teach specially if he is using a website that we are not familiar of [geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/) is the site.

And he gave us this problem:

1. A particle is being acted by the following forces:

   - F1 = 4.0N, 30 North of West
   - F3 = 8N, 54 South of West

     Find the Resultant

he told us to use the parallelogram method and because of my stupidity i cannot solve it using the website or physically write it down. can someone explain with visuals?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Do you know that forces can be represented as arrows with magnitude and direction?

Comment: @Ennar yes i know that

Comment: Then, what exactly is your issue here? You have magnitudes and directions, so draw the arrows.